# Seeking birth record for Thomas Eustice who married at Helston, Cornwall in 1867?

Tags: 19th-century, england, birth-records, cornwall

Cannot find birth  record for Thomas EUSTICE. At time of his marriage, Helston Registry Office, Cornwall,Dec.28 1867, to Matilda GAY, he is shown as an agricultural labourer, living at Wendron St., Helston. His father is shown as John EUSTICE, engine worker in a tin mine.

---

I am unable to find any verifiable proof, any sort of provable valid record of a Christina Dunstan (or variations) marrying a John Eustice in Cornwall in the 1800s. Nor can I find any such record for a Thomas Eustice living with a John and Christina Eustice (all spelling variations included) in the 1800s.

Thomas Eustice married Matilda Gay in 1867, the Marriage Certificate says, that his father was John Eustice, Wendron St., Helston but there is no Thomas Eustice living with a John and Christina Eustice in the 1851 or 1861 Censuses. Also no birth certificate or christening record exists for such a person. Plus, it seems quite a coincidence that Thomas and Matilda have son, Thomas John born on 3rd. April 1874. Father and son sharing the same birthday?

The Thomas Henry E. mentioned in an answer is not the same person as my checking further has shown.

The options/avenues suggested so far in answers have been explored in over thirty five years of searching.

Comment: Was John married to a Betsy by any chance?

Comment: Quite a few [Helston Parish Records](http://freepages.genealogy.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~cricket5/hel.htm) are available online but I don't think the one you are after is there.

Comment: How old was Thomas recorded to be at the time of his marriage?

Comment: Just wanted to mention that there are guidelines in the help center about [how to ask a good question](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  I understand that it is not always practical to put a summary of one's entire 35-year research history in a question.  However, when there is no prior research shown, people reading your question won't see that you are not a newbie starting from zero, and they will be tempted to go after the 'low-hanging fruit'.

Answer (score 4):

In the 1871 Census Thomas and Matilda are living in St Keverne and John's age is reported as being 21, born St Keverne. In [**FreeBMD**](http://www.freebmd.org.uk/cgi/information.pl?cite=9LOYXz9jcXMZRi2q0%2bpcZQ&scan=1) there's a birth of a Thomas Henry Eustice, March Qtr, 1849 and registered in Helston RD which included St Keverne. Have you bought this cert?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Elizabeth. I like (and appreciate) this answer. You might embed a link to the referenced "FreeBMD."

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy and Family History SE! I've removed the signature from your post per the [FAQ](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures). Your posts are always pre-signed, so no use re-signing them.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas Eustice:

Birth: 3 Apr 1850  - Cornwall, England

MARRIAGE: 28 Dec 1867 - Helston, Cornwall

DEATH: 18 Mar 1894

PARENTS:  John Eustice, Christina Dunston

SPOUSE:  Matilda Gay

Comment: Friendly reminder that when references are not provided _with_ the answer, we have no way of knowing whether the information was pulled from an unsourced public tree or from an otherwise elusive vital record collection.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the age shown for Thomas on his marriage certificate, the Thomas Eustice whose birth was registered in Q1 1838 (Volume 9, Page 120) at Helston would appear to be a candidate.

If his age was recorded as about 29 years then this may well be him, or if it just says Full Age, then I think it would still be worth trying to view that Birth Certificate.

There was also a birth registered for Thomas Eustis in Q4 1842 at Helston (Vol.IX, Page 130) but there is a separate marriage recorded for Thomas Eustis in Q4 1867 (Vol.5C, Page 354) at Helston so this seems less likely to be your Thomas Eustice.